# Rails Devise After Sending Password Reset Instructions it redirects to the wrong page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, passwords

I'm using devise in my rails app. For some reason when you click on the button to "Send Password Reset Instructions", after inputting your email, it brings you to a blank page with this url `/users/password.user`. I have no idea as to why its doing this nor how to change it.

I don't know exactly what code to post, so just comment what excerpts you want me to add. Thanks.

For the record, the password reset email and change password token works perfectly, its only this odd redirect (or lack of redirect).

These are the routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations', :invitations => 'invitations', :confirmations => 'confirmations'}, :except => [:show]
```

The password path helper is `edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @resource.reset_password_token)`

The config.reset_password_keys:

```
config.reset_password_keys = [ :login ]
```

Password Reset Form:

```
            <head>
              <%= stylesheet_link_tag "passreset" %>  
            </head>

            <body>

                <div id="box">
                        <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>
                            <%= devise_error_messages! %>

                                <%= f.text_field :id,:name => "user[login]", :placeholder => "Username or Email"%>

                                <input name="commit" type="submit" name="" value="Submit" />
                        <% end %>
                </div>
            </body>
```

Comment: can you post your routes? (or at least just the devise and user part), and also the path helper in the reset passwords email template

Comment: Sorry for the late update, was out of town. Here are what I think you wanted, if you would like more, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was a bad link in your reset password email, can you post your config.reset_password_keys (in devise config file) and your reset password form

Comment: Again, sorry for the late update (really late this time). Anyways, like I said, the email is being sent. It just has to do with after clicking the 'send' button, it takes you to a blank page.

Comment: Refreshing will send ANOTHER email.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it seems that your need to edit your views or the devise init file => config/initializers/devise.rb

You can edit your views by running the devise generator
rails generate devise:views users

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem.  For us it turned out that Devise was logging us out when we edited our own account.  We used the sign_in() devise helper and ended up using this code:

user_controller

def update

```
# need to know if user is changing their own password for re-sign in purposes.
is_current_user =  (@user == current_user)

password_change = !params[:user][:password].empty?
if (password_change)
  @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
else
  @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
end

if is_current_user # Devise signs us out, so...
  sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
end


@user.has_temp_password = false
@user.save!

if is_current_user
  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Your account was successfully updated.'
else
  redirect_to users_path, notice: 'The user was successfully updated.'
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the url in form to

```
:url => password_path(resource_name)
```